# axios POST not working, but working in postman

Tags: django, reactjs, post, django-rest-framework, axios

In a Django rests framework + Reactjs virtual environment:

I have an axios post call as follows:

```
   var data = JSON.stringify({diagnosis: diagnosis, frequency: frequency});

    axios.post('/by/frequency/'+id, data, {
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            }
    });
```

which gives me the following error:

```
POST http://localhost:8000/by/frequency/86 403 (Forbidden)
```

my json console.log output:

```
{"diagnosis":"strep throat","frequency":3}
```

However, when I do a post request in postman, it succeed as seen in the screenshot below:

[image]

I've been working on this for several hours and can't figure out why.

Comment: try with `dataType: "JSON"` in your POST request

Comment: see answer. why does chrome not work?

Comment: In your browser console, does it show anything related to preflight Access-Control-Allow-Origin ?

Comment: Nothing in the browser - just a forbidden 403 on the url

Comment: django needs a `csrf token` as header, as I show in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/49046916/7707749

Comment: Did you ever figure out why you were having this issue?