# 500 (Internal Server Error) AJAX Django

Tags: ajax, django, django-models

all! Can u please help me? I have a small problem. When i click button, When I click on a button, a new object should be created without reloading the page. Only one parameter is required to create an object.

The problem is that when you click the object is created (the new object is displayed in the admin panel), but in the console js there is an error:
`Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)`

JS:

```
function initBuyButton(){
    $('.button-buy').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var test = $(this);
        var smartphone_id = test.data("smartphone_id");
        var url = test.attr("action");

        basketUpdating(smartphone_id, url);
    });
}


function basketUpdating(smartphone_id, url){
    var data = {};
    var csrf_token = $('#form_buying_product [name="csrfmiddlewaretoken"]').val();

    data["csrfmiddlewaretoken"] = csrf_token;
    data.smartphone_id = smartphone_id;

    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: 'POST',
        data: data,
        cache: true,
    });
}


$(document).ready(function(){
    initBuyButton();
});
```

View:

```
def basket_adding(request):
    """Add new smartphone to basket."""
    data = request.POST
    smartphone_id = data.get('smartphone_id')
    SmartphoneInBasket.objects.create(smartphone_id=smartphone_id)

    return True
```

HTML:

```
<form id="form_buying_product" > {% csrf_token %}
  {% for sm in smartphones %}
 ...    
    <input type="submit" action="{% url 'basket_adding' %}" class="button-
     buy" data-smartphone_id = "{{ sm.id }}" value="Buy">
  {% endfor %}
</form>
```

Comment: try to update `DEBUG=True` in the settings file, that makes a readable error traceback

Comment: You should look at the error traceback in the server console or the Network tab of the browser dev tools.

Comment: `File "/home/fantbook/.pyenv/versions/ps/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 41, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/home/fantbook/.pyenv/versions/ps/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/deprecation.py", line 142, in __call__
    response = self.process_response(request, response)
  File "/home/fantbook/.pyenv/versions/ps/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/middleware/common.py", line 115, in process_response
    if response.status_code == 404:
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'status_code' `
 @DanielRoseman

Comment: You can't return `True` from a view, you must return a `http.HttpResponse(..)` object.

Comment: You should also add success and error handlers to your ajax call.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, a view needs to return an HttpResponse. If you want, it can be n empty:

```
return HttpResponse()
```

Comment: If you're not going to do anything with the return value then this is definitely the best/simplest way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to include the `csrf token` as a header.

```
var csrftoken = $("[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]").val();

$.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: 'POST',
    headers:{
        "X-CSRFToken": csrftoken
    },
    data: data,
    cache: true,
});
```

Because an `error 500` is that your permission gets denied to send the data.

Answer (score 0):

I have the following helper functions defined:

```
import json

def json_response(request, val, **kw):
    """Return a json or jsonp response.
    """
    if request.GET.get('callback'):
        return jsonp(request.GET['callback'], val, **kw)
    else:
        return jsonval(val, **kw)

def jsonval(val, **kw):
    """Serialize val to a json HTTP response.
    """
    data = dumps(val, **kw)
    resp = http.HttpResponse(data, content_type='application/json')
    resp['Content-Type'] = 'application/json; charset=UTF-8'
    return resp

def jsonp(callback, val, **kw):
    """Serialization with json callback.
    """
    data = callback + '(%s)' % json.dumps(val, **kw)

    return http.HttpResponse(
        data,
        content_type='application/javascript; charset=utf-8'
    )
```

with those defined your view can return a json object (to your ajax call):

```
def basket_adding(request):
    """Add new smartphone to basket."""
    ...
    return json_response(request, True)
```

it's common practice to return an object though, so perhaps:

```
    return json_response(request, {"status": True})
```